# Smarty only expands the default block once

Tags: php, smarty, block, extends, overwrite

We use Smarty 4.0 with PHP 8.0.
We have a default template from which everything else starts.
This is followed by a custom template and a series of plugins that also change and extend template files from the default template.

Now we have the problem that as soon as a Cutsom template and at least one plugin want to extend the same block from the default, only the block from the first loaded plugin is executed. It doesn't matter whether we use prepend or append for the extending blocks. What can be the reason?

Default-Template Block:

```
{block name='index_bodytag_top'}
        <body class="controller--{$pagedata.controller_name} page{$page_id}">
{/block}
```

Plugin 1:

```
{extends file='index.tpl'}

{block name="index_bodytag_top" prepend}
    THINGS FROM PLUGIN 1
{/block}
```

Plugin 2:

```
{extends file='index.tpl'}

{block name="index_bodytag_top" prepend}
    THINGS FROM PLUGIN 2
{/block}
```

Output in frontend:

- Things from the Default-Template
- Things from Plugin 1
- Nothing from Plugin 2

I've already tried swapping "prepend" and "append" and using both blocks the same way. I also tried to change the loading of the templates. Currently they load like this:

```
$template_source        = array();
$template_display       = "extends:file:[default]index.tpl";
$template_source['default']   = './template/default/';

foreach ($event_Frontend_Pages_ContentModules AS $wert) {
    $template_source[$wert['name']]     = './plugins/'.$wert['folder'].'/views/';

    $template_display                   .="|file:[custom]plugins/".$wert['folder']."/index.tpl";
    
}

$template_source['custom']   = './template/'.$GLOBALS['config_system']['template']['template_folder'].'/';
$template_display       .= "|file:[custom]index.tpl";
```

Comment: In the "Default-Template Block",  should you really have an extra `{/block}` at the end of (but inside) the body's `class=""` attribute?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint. I copied that wrong here.